# Why does Entity Framework Lambda convert 2 group joins into a Union All?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a query with multiple joins and 2 group joins. The group joins are of child records that can have 1 or more records attached, and I want to show them all.
The query works, however it is extremely slow. **When more than 1 group join is used, entity framework writes it as a union all.** Which is what I don't understand.
**Is there a way to rewrite the query so that ef doesn't write it as a union all? Or do I have to find another solution?**

This is the lambda code

```
var query = db.DocumentModsums
                .Join(db.Documents, 
                    data => data.DocumentId, 
                    d => d.Id, 
                    (data, d) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data,
                        Document = d,
                    })
                .Join(db.Modsums, 
                    data => data.DocumentModsum.ModsumId,
                    m => m.Id,
                    (data, m) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data.DocumentModsum,
                        Document = data.Document,
                        Modsum = m,
                    })
                .Join(db.MethodsOwnerships, 
                    data => data.Document.MethodsOwnershipId,
                    mo => mo.Id,
                    (data, mo) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data.DocumentModsum,
                        Document = data.Document,
                        Modsum = data.Modsum,
                        MethodsOwnership = mo,
                    })
                .Join(db.DocumentStatus,
                    data => data.Document.DocumentStatusId,
                    ds => ds.Id,
                    (data, ds) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data.DocumentModsum,
                        Document = data.Document,
                        Modsum = data.Modsum,
                        MethodsOwnership = data.MethodsOwnership,
                        DocumentStatus = ds,
                    })
                .Join(db.DocumentTypes,
                    data => data.Document.DocumentTypeId,
                    dt => dt.Id,
                    (data, dt) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data.DocumentModsum,
                        Document = data.Document,
                        Modsum = data.Modsum,
                        MethodsOwnership = data.MethodsOwnership,
                        DocumentStatus = data.DocumentStatus,
                        DocumentType = dt,
                    })
                .Join(db.ModsumStatus,
                    data => data.Modsum.ModsumStatusId,
                    ms => ms.Id,
                    (data, ms) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data.DocumentModsum,
                        Document = data.Document,
                        Modsum = data.Modsum,
                        MethodsOwnership = data.MethodsOwnership,
                        DocumentStatus = data.DocumentStatus,
                        DocumentType = data.DocumentType,
                        ModsumStatus = ms,
                    })
                .Join(db.ModsumTypes, 
                    data => data.Modsum.ModsumTypeId, 
                    mt => mt.Id, 
                    (data, mt) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data.DocumentModsum,
                        Document = data.Document,
                        Modsum = data.Modsum,
                        MethodsOwnership = data.MethodsOwnership,
                        DocumentStatus = data.DocumentStatus,
                        DocumentType = data.DocumentType,
                        ModsumStatus = data.ModsumStatus,
                        ModsumType = mt,
                    })
                .GroupJoin(db.SummaryOfActions,
                    data => data.Document.Id,
                    soa => soa.DocumentId,
                    (data, soa) => new
                    {
                        DocumentModsum = data.DocumentModsum,
                        Document = data.Document,
                        Modsum = data.Modsum,
                        MethodsOwnership = data.MethodsOwnership,
                        DocumentStatus = data.DocumentStatus,
                        DocumentType = data.DocumentType,
                        ModsumStatus = data.ModsumStatus,
                        ModsumType = data.ModsumType,
                        CIN = soa.Join(db.CINs,
                                soa2 => soa2.CINId,
                                cin2 => cin2.Id,
                                (soa2, cin2) => new
                                {
                                    CIN = cin2,
                                    SOA = soa2
                                }
                                ).Where(s => s.SOA.DeletedAt == null && s.CIN.DeletedAt == null)
                                .GroupBy(c => new { c.CIN.CINName })
                                .Select(c => c.Key.CINName)
                                .ToList()

                    })                    
                .GroupJoin(
                    db.ModsumEffectivities, 
                    data => data.Modsum.Id, 
                    me => me.ModsumId, 
                    (data, me) => new
                    {
                        Data = data,
                        ModsumEffectivity = me.Where(meff => meff.DeletedAt == null).Select(m2 => new ModsumEffectivityVM()
                        {
                            AircraftFrom = m2.AircraftFromId.ToString(),
                            AircraftFromId = m2.AircraftFromId,
                            AircraftTo = m2.AircraftToId.ToString(),
                            AircraftToId = m2.AircraftToId,                                
                            AircraftModelId = m2.AircraftModelId
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    })                    
                .Where(dm => dm.Data.DocumentModsum.DeletedAt == null
                    && dm.Data.Document.DeletedAt == null
                    && dm.Data.Modsum.DeletedAt == null
                    && dm.Data.MethodsOwnership.DeletedAt == null
                    && dm.Data.DocumentStatus.DeletedAt == null
                    && dm.Data.DocumentType.DeletedAt == null
                    && dm.Data.ModsumStatus.DeletedAt == null
                    && dm.Data.ModsumType.DeletedAt == null
                )
                .Select(data => new DocumentVM()
                {
                    Id = data.Data.DocumentModsum.Id,
                    Status = data.Data.DocumentStatus.Description,
                    DocumentNumber = data.Data.Document.DocumentNumber,
                    DocumentRevision = data.Data.Document.DocumentRevision,
                    DocumentTitle = data.Data.Document.DocumentTitle,
                    ModsumNumber = data.Data.Modsum.ModsumNumber,
                    ModsumRevision = data.Data.Modsum.ModsumRevision,
                    ModsumTitle = data.Data.Modsum.ModsumTitle,
                    DocumentType = data.Data.DocumentType.Description,
                    MethodsOwnership = data.Data.MethodsOwnership.Description,
                    ModsumReleaseDate = data.Data.Modsum.MSReleaseDate,
                    ModsumAuthority = data.Data.Modsum.Authority ?? "",
                    CreatedAt = data.Data.DocumentModsum.CreatedAt,
                    CIN = data.Data.Document.CIN,
                    CINList = data.Data.CIN,
                    ModsumEffectivity = data.ModsumEffectivity,                        
                }).ToList();
```

This converts into

```
SELECT 
[UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll1].[Id1] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[Id2] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll1].[Id3] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll1].[Id4] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll1].[Id5] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll1].[Id6] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll1].[Id7] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll1].[Description] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll1].[DocumentNumber] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll1].[DocumentRevision] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll1].[DocumentTitle] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll1].[ModsumNumber] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll1].[ModsumRevision] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll1].[ModsumTitle] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll1].[Description1] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll1].[Description2] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll1].[MSReleaseDate1] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll1].[CreatedAt] AS [C21], 
[UnionAll1].[CIN] AS [C22], 
[UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C23], 
[UnionAll1].[CINName] AS [C24], 
[UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C25], 
[UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C26]
FROM  (SELECT 
    [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], 
    [Limit1].[Id3] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[Id4] AS [Id1], 
    [Limit1].[Id5] AS [Id2], 
    [Limit1].[Id6] AS [Id3], 
    [Limit1].[Id7] AS [Id4], 
    [Limit1].[Id1] AS [Id5], 
    [Limit1].[Id2] AS [Id6], 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C2], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id7], 
    [Limit1].[Description1] AS [Description], 
    [Limit1].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], 
    [Limit1].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], 
    [Limit1].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], 
    [Limit1].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], 
    [Limit1].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], 
    [Limit1].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], 
    [Limit1].[Description2] AS [Description1], 
    [Limit1].[Description] AS [Description2], 
    [Limit1].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate1], 
    [Limit1].[C2] AS [C3], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Limit1].[CIN] AS [CIN], 
    [Project3].[CINName] AS [CINName], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C5]
    FROM   (SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], [Project1].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], [Project1].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], [Project1].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], [Project1].[CIN] AS [CIN], [Project1].[Id2] AS [Id2], [Project1].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], [Project1].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], [Project1].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], [Project1].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], [Project1].[Id3] AS [Id3], [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], [Project1].[Id4] AS [Id4], [Project1].[Description1] AS [Description1], [Project1].[Id5] AS [Id5], [Project1].[Description2] AS [Description2], [Project1].[Id6] AS [Id6], [Project1].[Id7] AS [Id7], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[C2] AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Filter1].[Id8] AS [Id], 
            [Filter1].[CreatedAt1] AS [CreatedAt], 
            [Filter1].[Id9] AS [Id1], 
            [Filter1].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], 
            [Filter1].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], 
            [Filter1].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], 
            [Filter1].[CIN] AS [CIN], 
            [Filter1].[Id10] AS [Id2], 
            [Filter1].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], 
            [Filter1].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], 
            [Filter1].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], 
            [Filter1].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], 
            [Filter1].[Id11] AS [Id3], 
            [Filter1].[Description3] AS [Description], 
            [Filter1].[Id12] AS [Id4], 
            [Filter1].[Description4] AS [Description1], 
            [Filter1].[Id13] AS [Id5], 
            [Filter1].[Description5] AS [Description2], 
            [Filter1].[Id14] AS [Id6], 
            [Extent8].[Id] AS [Id7], 
            1 AS [C1], 
            CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Authority] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Filter1].[Authority] END AS [C2]
            FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id8], [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt1], [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id9], [Extent2].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], [Extent2].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], [Extent2].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], [Extent2].[CIN] AS [CIN], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id10], [Extent3].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], [Extent3].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], [Extent3].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], [Extent3].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], [Extent3].[ModsumTypeId] AS [ModsumTypeId], [Extent3].[Authority] AS [Authority], [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id11], [Extent4].[Description] AS [Description3], [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id12], [Extent5].[Description] AS [Description4], [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id13], [Extent6].[Description] AS [Description5], [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id14]
                FROM       [dbo].[DocumentModsums] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[DocumentId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Modsums] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ModsumId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[MethodsOwnerships] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[MethodsOwnershipId] = [Extent4].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DocumentStatus] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[DocumentStatusId] = [Extent5].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DocumentTypes] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent2].[DocumentTypeId] = [Extent6].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ModsumStatus] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent3].[ModsumStatusId] = [Extent7].[Id]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent5].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent6].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent7].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) ) AS [Filter1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ModsumTypes] AS [Extent8] ON [Filter1].[ModsumTypeId] = [Extent8].[Id]
            WHERE [Extent8].[DeletedAt] IS NULL
        )  AS [Project1]
        ORDER BY [Project1].[MSReleaseDate] DESC
        OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY  ) AS [Limit1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT 
        [Distinct1].[CINName] AS [CINName], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent10].[CINName] AS [CINName]
            FROM  [dbo].[SummaryOfActions] AS [Extent9]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[CINs] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent9].[CINId] = [Extent10].[Id]
            WHERE ([Limit1].[Id1] = [Extent9].[DocumentId]) AND ([Extent9].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent10].[DeletedAt] IS NULL)
        )  AS [Distinct1] ) AS [Project3]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    2 AS [C1], 
    [Limit2].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], 
    [Limit2].[Id3] AS [Id], 
    [Limit2].[Id4] AS [Id1], 
    [Limit2].[Id5] AS [Id2], 
    [Limit2].[Id6] AS [Id3], 
    [Limit2].[Id7] AS [Id4], 
    [Limit2].[Id1] AS [Id5], 
    [Limit2].[Id2] AS [Id6], 
    [Limit2].[Id] AS [Id7], 
    [Limit2].[Id] AS [Id8], 
    [Limit2].[Description1] AS [Description], 
    [Limit2].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], 
    [Limit2].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], 
    [Limit2].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], 
    [Limit2].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], 
    [Limit2].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], 
    [Limit2].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], 
    [Limit2].[Description2] AS [Description1], 
    [Limit2].[Description] AS [Description2], 
    [Limit2].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate1], 
    [Limit2].[C1] AS [C2], 
    [Limit2].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Limit2].[CIN] AS [CIN], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
    [Extent19].[ModsumId] AS [ModsumId], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C4]
    FROM   (SELECT [Project5].[Id] AS [Id], [Project5].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Project5].[Id1] AS [Id1], [Project5].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], [Project5].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], [Project5].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], [Project5].[CIN] AS [CIN], [Project5].[Id2] AS [Id2], [Project5].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], [Project5].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], [Project5].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], [Project5].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], [Project5].[Id3] AS [Id3], [Project5].[Description] AS [Description], [Project5].[Id4] AS [Id4], [Project5].[Description1] AS [Description1], [Project5].[Id5] AS [Id5], [Project5].[Description2] AS [Description2], [Project5].[Id6] AS [Id6], [Project5].[Id7] AS [Id7], [Project5].[C1] AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Filter4].[Id15] AS [Id], 
            [Filter4].[CreatedAt2] AS [CreatedAt], 
            [Filter4].[Id16] AS [Id1], 
            [Filter4].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], 
            [Filter4].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], 
            [Filter4].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], 
            [Filter4].[CIN] AS [CIN], 
            [Filter4].[Id17] AS [Id2], 
            [Filter4].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], 
            [Filter4].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], 
            [Filter4].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], 
            [Filter4].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], 
            [Filter4].[Id18] AS [Id3], 
            [Filter4].[Description6] AS [Description], 
            [Filter4].[Id19] AS [Id4], 
            [Filter4].[Description7] AS [Description1], 
            [Filter4].[Id20] AS [Id5], 
            [Filter4].[Description8] AS [Description2], 
            [Filter4].[Id21] AS [Id6], 
            [Extent18].[Id] AS [Id7], 
            CASE WHEN ([Filter4].[Authority] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Filter4].[Authority] END AS [C1]
            FROM   (SELECT [Extent11].[Id] AS [Id15], [Extent11].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt2], [Extent12].[Id] AS [Id16], [Extent12].[DocumentNumber] AS [DocumentNumber], [Extent12].[DocumentRevision] AS [DocumentRevision], [Extent12].[DocumentTitle] AS [DocumentTitle], [Extent12].[CIN] AS [CIN], [Extent13].[Id] AS [Id17], [Extent13].[ModsumNumber] AS [ModsumNumber], [Extent13].[ModsumRevision] AS [ModsumRevision], [Extent13].[ModsumTitle] AS [ModsumTitle], [Extent13].[MSReleaseDate] AS [MSReleaseDate], [Extent13].[ModsumTypeId] AS [ModsumTypeId], [Extent13].[Authority] AS [Authority], [Extent14].[Id] AS [Id18], [Extent14].[Description] AS [Description6], [Extent15].[Id] AS [Id19], [Extent15].[Description] AS [Description7], [Extent16].[Id] AS [Id20], [Extent16].[Description] AS [Description8], [Extent17].[Id] AS [Id21]
                FROM       [dbo].[DocumentModsums] AS [Extent11]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent11].[DocumentId] = [Extent12].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Modsums] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent11].[ModsumId] = [Extent13].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[MethodsOwnerships] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent12].[MethodsOwnershipId] = [Extent14].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DocumentStatus] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent12].[DocumentStatusId] = [Extent15].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DocumentTypes] AS [Extent16] ON [Extent12].[DocumentTypeId] = [Extent16].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ModsumStatus] AS [Extent17] ON [Extent13].[ModsumStatusId] = [Extent17].[Id]
                WHERE ([Extent11].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent12].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent13].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent14].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent15].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent16].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) AND ([Extent17].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) ) AS [Filter4]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ModsumTypes] AS [Extent18] ON [Filter4].[ModsumTypeId] = [Extent18].[Id]
            WHERE [Extent18].[DeletedAt] IS NULL
        )  AS [Project5]
        ORDER BY [Project5].[MSReleaseDate] DESC
        OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY  ) AS [Limit2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ModsumEffectivities] AS [Extent19] ON [Limit2].[Id2] = [Extent19].[ModsumId]) AS [UnionAll1]
ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[MSReleaseDate] DESC, [UnionAll1].[Id] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id1] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id2] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id3] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id4] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id5] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id6] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id7] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: Have you considered making a view in SQL server that returns the values needed.  Sql is much better at handling joins than EF is.

Answer (score 0):

EF, or most ORMs to be honest, they will generally use a "safe" way to generate a query.  This means that there may be more efficient ways to write the same query but it won't always work correctly.  This is generally an issue with generated code, when there is a solution that covers more scenarios it will be applied in all cases.  However, as you indicated, there may be a better way to write the lambda expressions and achieve a better performing query.  I see a few things that I might try, however I can't attempt to ensure this will work without first creating an EF code base to replicate your design.

In words, I would try to move the group joins to exist within the table it is joining.  So the SummaryOfActions' group join would exist within the Documents' join and the ModsumEffectivities' group join would exist within the Modsums' join.

That is the only thing I can think of that might cause the query to be generated in a more efficient fashion.

On a side note, when you are creating anonymous types (new{foo})you don't need to specify the name (new{foo=foo}) unless you want them to use a different name than the variable.

I tried to make these changes to your query in notepad so there may be some errors, but give this a try...

```
  var query = db.DocumentModsums
    .Join(db.Documents,
      data => data.DocumentId,
      d => d.Id,
      (data, doc) => new
      {
        DocumentModsum = data,
        Document = new {
          doc.MethodsOwnershipId,
          doc.DocumentStatusId,
          doc.DocumentTypeId,
          doc.DeletedAt,
          doc.DocumentNumber,
          doc.DocumentRevision,
          doc.DocumentTitle,
          doc.CIN,
          SoaCinNames = db.SummaryOfActions
                          .Join(db.CINs, soa => soa.CINId, cin => cin.Id, (soa, cin) => new { CIN = cin, SOA = soa })
                          .Where(s => s.SOA.DocumentId == doc.Id && s.SOA.DeletedAt == null && s.CIN.DeletedAt == null)
                          .GroupBy(c => c.CIN.CINName)
                          .Select(c => c.Key )}
      }
    )
    .Join(db.Modsums,
      data => data.DocumentModsum.ModsumId,
      m => m.Id,
      (data, mod) => new
      {
        data.DocumentModsum,
        data.Document,
        Modsum = new
        {
          mod.ModsumStatusId,
          mod.ModsumTypeId,
          mod.ModsumNumber,
          mod.ModsumRevision,
          mod.ModsumTitle,
          mod.MSReleaseDate,
          mod.Authority,
          mod.DeletedAt,
          Effectivities = db.ModsumEffectivities
                                         .Where(me => me.ModsumId == mod.Id && me.DeletedAt == null)
                                         .Select(m2 => new ModsumEffectivityVM
                                         {
                                           AircraftFrom = m2.AircraftFromId.ToString(),
                                           AircraftFromId = m2.AircraftFromId,
                                           AircraftTo = m2.AircraftToId.ToString(),
                                           AircraftToId = m2.AircraftToId,
                                           AircraftModelId = m2.AircraftModelId
                                         })
        }
      }
    )
    .Join(db.MethodsOwnerships,
      data => data.Document.MethodsOwnershipId,
      mo => mo.Id,
      (data, mo) => new
      {
        data.DocumentModsum,
        data.Document,
        data.Modsum,
        MethodsOwnership = mo
      })
    .Join(db.DocumentStatus,
      data => data.Document.DocumentStatusId,
      ds => ds.Id,
      (data, ds) => new
      {
        data.DocumentModsum,
        data.Document,
        data.Modsum,
        data.MethodsOwnership,
        DocumentStatus = ds
      })
    .Join(db.DocumentTypes,
      data => data.Document.DocumentTypeId,
      dt => dt.Id,
      (data, dt) => new
      {
        data.DocumentModsum,
        data.Document,
        data.Modsum,
        data.MethodsOwnership,
        data.DocumentStatus,
        DocumentType = dt
      })
    .Join(db.ModsumStatus,
      data => data.Modsum.ModsumStatusId,
      ms => ms.Id,
      (data, ms) => new
      {
        data.DocumentModsum,
        data.Document,
        data.Modsum,
        data.MethodsOwnership,
        data.DocumentStatus,
        data.DocumentType,
        ModsumStatus = ms
      })
    .Join(db.ModsumTypes,
      data => data.Modsum.ModsumTypeId,
      mt => mt.Id,
      (data, ModsumType) => new
      {
        data.DocumentModsum,
        data.Document,
        data.Modsum,
        data.MethodsOwnership,
        data.DocumentStatus,
        data.DocumentType,
        data.ModsumStatus,
        ModsumType,
      })
    .Where(data => data.DocumentModsum.DeletedAt == null
                   && data.Document.DeletedAt == null
                   && data.Modsum.DeletedAt == null
                   && data.MethodsOwnership.DeletedAt == null
                   && data.DocumentStatus.DeletedAt == null
                   && data.DocumentType.DeletedAt == null
                   && data.ModsumStatus.DeletedAt == null
                   && data.ModsumType.DeletedAt == null
    )
    .Select(data => new DocumentVM()
    {
      Id = data.DocumentModsum.Id,
      Status = data.DocumentStatus.Description,
      DocumentNumber = data.Document.DocumentNumber,
      DocumentRevision = data.Document.DocumentRevision,
      DocumentTitle = data.Document.DocumentTitle,
      ModsumNumber = data.Modsum.ModsumNumber,
      ModsumRevision = data.Modsum.ModsumRevision,
      ModsumTitle = data.Modsum.ModsumTitle,
      DocumentType = data.DocumentType.Description,
      MethodsOwnership = data.MethodsOwnership.Description,
      ModsumReleaseDate = data.Modsum.MSReleaseDate,
      ModsumAuthority = data.Modsum.Authority ?? "",
      CreatedAt = data.DocumentModsum.CreatedAt,
      CIN = data.Document.CIN,
      CINList = data.Document.SoaCinNames.ToList(),
      ModsumEffectivity = data.Modsum.Effectivities.ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it still does the same thing. If there's one group join there's no Union all, but when I add the other, the union all comes back. I even tried doing the group joins inside the document and modsum joins, but it's still the same thing.

Comment: If you tried what I posted just ignore the rest of this comment, otherwise my example above doesn't actually have any .GroupJoins and you should give it a try.

Comment: I did try what you suggested. It still turns it into a Union All.

Comment: Are you always using the entire List<DocumentVM> in the query object?  Or do you filter it down with with .Where(...) calls?